# ¿Convertir valor varchar a tinyint?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Tengo un valor en un textbox (varchar) en un webform de asp .net y necesito compararlo con un valor tipo tinyint de sql.

Cual seria la manera?

Gracias

Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: para empezar, un valor en un textbox es un string, varchar es un tipo de datos en una base de datos. Un tinyint no existe en C#, asi que podrias suponer que es un int (que sobra), por lo cual basta con castear (si se puede) el string a int y compararlos. Ahora, eso te genero problemas porque?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer este articulo.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data

Ahí se puede observar la relación de datos entre los distintos tipos de dato de SQL y C#

En tu caso, para poder insertar tinyint debes usar **Byte**

```
string a = "1";
Byte b;

b = Convert.ToByte(a);

Byte c = 0;

if(b>c){
.......
}
```

Espero que te sirva.. Saludos